# Converse of Jensen's inequality

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and for all bounded measurable $f$,
$$
\varphi\Big(\int_0^1fd\lambda\Big) \le \int_0^1\varphi(f)d\lambda
$$
I'm asked to prove that $\varphi$ is a convex function.
I have no idea how to even begin, only idea I've had is to try to suppose that $\varphi''(x)<0$ for some $x\in(0,1)$ but then I haven't got a clue.

Comment: This is much simpler than the Jensen's inequality itself. Just recall the definition of convexity, and try to pick your $f$ to arrive at it exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and $t\in(0,1)$, consider
$$
f(s) = \begin{cases} x & s\leq t \\ y & s>t. \end{cases}
$$
Then your inequality tells
$$
\phi(tx+(1-t)y) \leq t\phi(x)+(1-t)\phi(y).
$$