# Prove that $\varphi$ is convex if $\varphi \left[ \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \right] \le \int_0^1 \varphi [f(x)] \, dx$ for any measurable $f$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> Q: Suppose $\varphi$ is a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that:
>   \begin{align*}
>   \varphi \left[ \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \right] &\le \int_0^1 \varphi [f(x)] \, dx \\
> \end{align*}
>   for every real valued bounded measurable function $f$ on $[0,1]$. Prove that $\varphi$ is convex.

My attempt:

Consider for fixed $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$:

\begin{align*}
  f(\theta) &= \theta x_1 + (1 - \theta) x_2 \\
  \int_0^1 f(\theta) \, d\theta &= x_1 \int_0^1 \theta \, d\theta + x^2 \int_0^1 (1 - \theta) \, d\theta = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} \\
\end{align*}

Plugging this into the inequality given in the problem:

\begin{align*}
  \varphi \left[ \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} \right] &\le \int_0^1 \varphi [\theta x_1 + (1 - \theta) x_2] \, d\theta \\  
\end{align*}

From here, I'm stuck. If I can show the midpoint property:

\begin{align*}
  \varphi \left( \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} \right) &\le \frac{\varphi(x_1) + \varphi(x_2)}{2} \\
\end{align*}

I know proofs from there that $\varphi$ is convex. But I don't see how to get that.

Comment: This is actually the converse of Jensen's inequality. See this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007917/converse-of-jensens-inequality

Comment: Note that you need that $\varphi$ is continuous when using the argument with the midpoint-convexity. You don't assume continuity here.