# Equality in Jensen's inequality for non convex functions

Tags: inequality, jensen-inequality

Jensen's inequality, $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]\geq\phi(\mathbb{E}[X])$, holds for any convex function $\phi$ and random variable $X$.

Given that $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]=\phi(\mathbb{E}[X])$ for some non-degenerate random variable $X$, what can we say about $\phi$? any why? (assuming that it is not necessarily convex). What about the case in which $\phi$ is differentiable?
I wonder if there is an interesting universal property on all function $\phi$ that lead to such equality.

Comment: Do you mean "holds for *all* measurable (and integrable) $f$", not for "some"? Otherwise, $\phi(0)=0$ is a sufficient condition (it will hold for $f=0$).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited my post. I am looking for a non-trivial property.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3007917 – Oops, the question changed again...

Comment: Yeah sorry, iterating for conciseness.

Comment: Are you assuming that equality holds for *all* $X$ (or for all functions $f$ in your previous version) or just that it holds for *some* $X$?

Comment: I assume that it holds for some $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is much that can be said without more restrictions. If $X$ is some random variable such that $P(X=E[X]) = 0$, then for any function $\phi$ you can define $\tilde{\phi}(t) = \begin{cases} \phi(t) & t \ne E[X] \\ E[\phi(X)] & t = E[X] \end{cases}$ to get $\tilde{\phi}(E[X]) := E[\phi(X)] = E[\tilde{\phi}(X)]$.

Comment: What if $\phi$ is differentiable?

Comment: @GuyOhayon If $P(E[X] - \epsilon < X < E[X] + \epsilon) = 0$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ (this might happen for discrete $X$, for example), then I think you can similarly deform $\phi$ smoothly on the interval $[E[X] - \epsilon, E[X] + \epsilon]$ so that $\tilde{\phi}(E[X])=E[\phi(X)]$.